# Is there a way to use Linear gradient along with HSLA?

Tags: javascript, css

Im trying to set my background colour based off a formula and HSLA but i want to use it as a Linear gradient.This is what i have, but returns no colour for the last else if statement

```
if (oneCallDataFromApi && oneCallDataFromApi.current.temp) {
    if (kelvinToCelcius(oneCallDataFromApi.current.temp) >= 10) {
      var lightness = (100 - (kelvinToCelcius(oneCallDataFromApi.current.temp))); 
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = `hsla(20,100%,${lightness}%,0.9)`;
    } else if (kelvinToCelcius(oneCallDataFromApi.current.temp) < 10) {
      lightness = (50 + (kelvinToCelcius(oneCallDataFromApi.current.temp)));
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = `linear-gradient(179.31deg, 180,50%,${lightness}%) 9.28%, #F4AC4E 167.45%)`;
    }
```

**Edit:**

By changing "document.body.style.backgroundColor" to simply "document.body.style.background" worked for me lol

Answer (score 0):

By changing "document.body.style.backgroundColor" to simply "document.body.style.background" worked for me lol

Answer (score -2):

Would be easier, and i mean soooo much easier, if you used css gradient instead of javascript gradient tools or whatever.

such as something cool like this

```css
html{
background: rgb(2,0,36);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 1%, rgba(9,121,114,1) 31%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 63%);
}
p{
color:white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<p>Hello there, I'm Lorem</p>
</html>
```

You can use this  [website](https://cssgradient.io/)  for all your gradient needs

Comment: there's always some kind stranger that has probably made a website tool to make css development cut 90% of time in working in it

Comment: Think the problem with this is that im changing it based of a variable, so i want to make the colour dark the higher the temperature basically, but i still want to use a linear gradient for the color?

Comment: answer your own question